# How to can I run ngfor loop from ts in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to write generic code for all my apps that are of same use case. what I want to do is
get ref of the component in my html file and use it in my generic functions and  do *ngFor. Is it possible in ionic?

Answer (score 0):

This will work the exact same as any Angular project, because it is angular.

in .ts just initialize your array. Can be initialized from API as well. Just be sure to know your keys to use in the loop.

Ex.

```js
private countries: Country[] = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Japan',
        ports: [
          { id: 0, name: 'Tokai' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Russia',
        ports: [
          { id: 2, name: 'Vladivostok' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'India',
        ports: [
          { id: 3, name: 'Navlakhi' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Cayman Islands',
        ports: [
          { id: 4, name: 'Cayman Brac' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Egypt',
        ports: [
          { id: 6, name: 'Port Ibrahim' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Finland',
        ports: [
          { id: 7, name: 'Brahestad' },
          { id: 37, name: 'Kantvik' }
        ]
      }, {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Germany',
        ports: [
          { id: 8, name: 'Brake' }
        ]
      }
   }];
```

In your html you can simply call it this way:

```html
<ion-content>
          <ion-grid *ngFor="let country of countries">
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col><b>ID:</b> {{country.ID}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ion-row>
                  <ion-col><b>Name:</b> {{country.Name}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
 </ion-content>
```